# Sqlite compartilhado entre flavors android

Tags: android, sqlite

Olá, estou querendo fazer uma versão paga sem anúncios do meu app que já está publicado na play store. Eu queria que se uma pessoa comprar a versão paga ela não perca todos os dados já cadastrados na versão gratuita, onde armazeno tudo no SQLite. Qual a maneira de compartilhar os dados do SQLite entre diferentes flavors no android?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa que as duas aplicações usem o mesmo id.

Adicione essa linha à ambos os manifesto:

```
android:sharedUserId="com.android.xyz"
```

Outra opção é através do [Custom Content Provider](https://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/custom-content-provider-in-android/).

Comment: Mas no android studio tem apenas um manifest. Devo criar uma pasta para cada flavor e em cada pasta usar um manifest diferente? Como fica a configuração do gradle? Cada flavor fica com o mesmo id e a mesma versão? E na hora de publicar a versão paga, na play store vai ficar como um app diferente?

Comment: Tem a opção paga e a free. Isso deve ser colocado no Manifest da versão paga e da versão free.